# how to call twitter api in jmeter?

Tags: twitter, jmeter

I can't call a twitter api using jmeter.

I always get a `403 http status code`. I used the same authorisation in postman and it works.

below is the authorisation I used in postman:

[oauth 1.0 in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrnAm.png)
Do I have to install new plugins or config the http authorization manager.? 
Can anyone provide me with the details how to call a twitter api.
for example this API: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend going for [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language so you will be able to:

- Either use [hbc library](https://github.com/twitter/hbc) (Twitter [official Java client](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries)) to call Twitter API methods
- Or go for [oauth-signpost](https://github.com/mttkay/signpost) library in order to build and sign your HTTP requests, this approach is described in details in the [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) guide